# Application throws 503 service error after leaving the app idle

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-platform

I have made a UI5 application that uses an OData service pointing to SAP Gateway. This works correctly, however, I am noticing that if the app is left idle for a period of time (approx 10 mins), then the app suddenly starts getting the following error when trying to use this service:

> "HTTP Status 503 - No application is available to handle this request"

Does anyone know why this could be happening and what I could do to fix this?
This is happening when running the app from the Web IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As you have included "sap-web-ide" tag in your question, I assume this timeout happens during development when you run your app from web ide.

This is the timeout session from  SAP Web IDE. Once time runs out, any call to the SAP Cloud Platform (including the one using a destination for your SAP Gateway system) will fail because your must reauthenticate (that can be done by refreshing the page).

If you deploy your app to SAP Cloud Platform or to your SAP Gateway system this short timeout won't happen.

Comment: Not sure about the last sentence. According to the doc: _After 20 minutes of inactivity user sessions are invalidated. If the user tries to access an invalidated session, SAP Cloud Platform returns a logon page_ ([source](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/de16793b391a4bcfae6096f34433de76.html)). I think this refers to the apps deployed to SCP.

Comment: This documentation refers to an app deployed in SAP Cloud Platform which is different than running your app from Web IDE from my understanding.

Comment: That's my understanding too. What I'm not sure about is whether the question author refers to the deployed app or app run from Web IDE

Comment: Not sure as well. From the tag `sap-web-ide` this is my assumption. And actually this timeout happens to me on a daily basis. I had never counted how much time passes until the timeout but it's really short.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, this issue is currently happening when running the app from the WebIDE, the app has not currently been deployed. So am I right in thinking that this issue will be resolved once the app is deployed ?

Comment: Yes. If you deploy to a netweaver system the timeout will be greater than 10 minutes for sure.